# Creating a service like google calendar. What database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, icalendar

I will need to create a service similar to google calendar (basic functions only) to view and edit/delete appointments using iCalendar format.
Before starting I would like to ask you, which kind of database is best suited for storing this kind of information. It has to be a scalable solution.

Thank you very much if you can help me.

Comment: Personally, I'd go with a relational database, because calendars and appointments have an inherent structure - but the question is highly subjective

Comment: This question is very open ended.  If you have a specific database feature you want to optimize for, that would be a better line of inquiry.  If not, then any database will do, pick whatever you like.

Comment: Thanks, I was just wondering if someone tried those new db systems except from mysql to achieve this and has some experience :). Performance is really important.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely use mysql, perhaps with PDO. This way yuo can always move to another database in the future if needed. However, for such task mySQL should be enough for life.

Comment: Thanks, PDO is an interesting idea. I will look into that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a scalable database, you can use NoSQL database (like MongoDB, CouchDB for exemple). This kind of database are made to be scalable.

But for a "google calendar" like with "basic functions", classic SQL database (like MySQL for exemple) would be large enough too. Even if you have lot's of users.

So NoSQL or SQL database are easy to use. So use the database you like the most.

Answer (score 1):

Given the broad scope of your question, you can use any relational database like:

1. MySQL
2. Postgree
3. SQL Server
4. Oracle

Or a NoSQL database like:

1. MongoDB
2. Raven DB

Your choose depends on the knowledge and experience with any of these databases.

Personally, I'd go with MySQL because it's stable, open source, there's lots of resources about it (including optimization tips) and it's "free".

Answer (score 1):

Asking about scalability is the wrong approach. You simply cannot know which kind of scalability problems you will run into if your service grows.

You can scale almost every database solution without any changes a certain amount. But eventually you'll have to take a radically different approach to the problem because the original solution cannot expand further.

For example, MySQL in high performance environments is used on servers that have enough RAM installed that the whole dataset at some point is hold in RAM, and the harddisk is only writing the whole time for persistence. The harddisk, btw, is a very fast array of SSD.

But even these titan servers might get too small, and tactics like "sharding" and "partitioning" must be applied to split the data set over multiple database servers. Master-slave-replication might be of use if reading and writing gets into each others way.

If you are starting, your basic question should be: What is the data structure I want to use for delivering the service to at least one user? Any database can support this, but some might be easier to use, depending on data structures and your knowledge of them.

If you have no service, you have no users, and the need for scaling diminishes.

Comment: That is true, but maybe there is a more elegant way to save calendars and appointments.